# "list indices must be integers" error, when trying to use keys from a dictionary

Tags: python, json, api, typeerror, openweathermap

I tried to use the `openweathermap.org` rest API inside python. When I tried to assign a key from the dictionary I created with the JSON data this error occurred.

```
-list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm new to python and I couldn't find a solution to this matter.
The code snip I wrote:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

lokka = str(input("What is the location you need information of?"))
#takes the location as "lokka"

hellload = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ lokka +"&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&units=metric")
#the rest api's load will be taken to the account of hellload

jputha = hellload.json()
#json data will be converted to a dictionary
#print (jputha)

#---------------------------------------------------------
#from now onward I'll be kickin the hell out the jsons
long = str(jputha["coord"]["lon"])
lat = str(jputha["coord"]["lat"])
wthr = str(jputha["weather"]["main"])
temp = str(jputha["main"]["temp"])
winspd = str(jputha["wind"]["speed"])

print(long)
print(lat)
print(wthr)
print(temp)
print(winspd)
```

Comment: can you please share what error you got?

Comment: `jputha["coord"]` returns the value associated to the key `"coord"` which in this case appears to be a list. A list however, cannot be indexed by its elements, only by integers. To further analyse your problem you should specify your `lokka` user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to OpenWeatherMap's [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON), the JSON response from the API looks like this:

```
{"coord":
{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":150},
"clouds":{"all":75},
"rain":{"3h":3},
"dt":1435658272,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
"id":2172797,
"name":"Cairns",
"cod":200}
```

where the `weather` key contains a list of dicts rather than a dict, so if you simply want the first weather data from the list, you should use `[0]` to obtain the value of the first index instead:

```
wthr = str(jputha["weather"][0]["main"])
```